# how to write the store procedure for searching (CSV)?

Tags: sql-server-2005

how can i write the store procedure for searching particular string in  a column of table, for given set of strings (CSV string).

like :  select * from xxx where tags like ('oscar','rahman','slumdog')

how can i write the procedure for that combination of tags.

Comment: Is there any reason that you need to parse the file using SQL Server as a RDBMS is better for storing data not and not really designed for parsing CSV files.

Comment: hi, Mr. Kane actually in my project i have a search buttons, there user can give any combination names . how can i write the storeprocedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a comma seperated string...

You could then apply this list to Oded example to create the `LIKE` parts of the `WHERE` cluase on the fly.

```
DECLARE @pos int, @curruntLocation char(20), @input varchar(2048)
SELECT @pos=0
SELECT @input = 'oscar,rahman,slumdog'
SELECT @input = @input + ','

CREATE TABLE #tempTable (temp varchar(100) )

WHILE CHARINDEX(',',@input) > 0
BEGIN
SELECT @pos=CHARINDEX(',',@input)
SELECT @curruntLocation = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@input,1,@pos-1)))
INSERT INTO #tempTable (temp) VALUES (@curruntLocation)
SELECT @input=SUBSTRING(@input,@pos+1,2048)
END

SELECT * FROM #tempTable
DR0P TABLE #tempTable
```

Comment: Mr. Kevchadders i modify like the procedure like this
create procedure scrap (@string varchar(200))
as
 
DECLARE @pos int, @curruntLocation char(20), @input varchar(2048)
SELECT @pos=0
SELECT @input = @string
SELECT @input = @input + ','

CREATE TABLE #tempTable (temp varchar(100) )

WHILE CHARINDEX(',',@input) > 0
BEGIN
SELECT @pos=CHARINDEX(',',@input)
SELECT @curruntLocation = RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@input,1,@pos-1))
INSERT INTO #tempTable (temp) VALUES (@curruntLocation)
SELECT @input=SUBSTRING(@input,@pos+1,2048)
END

 select * from videos where tags in( select * from #temptable)

Comment: when i run the procedure it is showing no column can u help me
i chage some code in the button of ur code can u look i send it the previous code thank you

Comment: dont forget to drop the temp table, and test to make sure data exists in the #temptable before you select from the vidoes table. e.g. place a SELECT * FROM #tempTable before Select * from Vidoes...

Comment: also i edited the SQL to add a LTRIM to the statement to make sure spaces on both sides where removed. Make sure you apply that as well. ps. i have to place a zero in dr0p table due to that command being blocked on my side. (you will need to replace 0 with o)

Answer (score 0):

First off, the use of `like` for exact matches is sub-optimal. Might as well use `=`, and if doing so, you can use the `IN` syntax:

```
select * from xxx 
where tags IN ('oscar', 'rahman', 'slumdog')
```

I am guessing you are not looking for an exact match, but for any record where the `tags` field contains *all* of the tags.

This would be something like this:

```
select * from xxx 
where tags like '%oscar%' 
  and tags like '%rahman%'
  and tags like '%slumdog%'
```

This would be not be very fast or performant though.

Think about moving this kind of logic into your application, where it is faster and easier to do.

**Edit:**

Following the comments - there are lots of examples on how to [parse](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2006/02/03/T-SQL-Parse-a-delimited-string.aspx) [delimited](http://codebetter.com/blogs/raymond.lewallen/archive/2005/10/26/133774.aspx) [strings](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/db2/library/techarticle/0303stolze/0303stolze1.html) out there. You can put these in a table and use [dynamic sql](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-dynamic-sql-part-1) to generate your query.

But, this will have bad performance and SQL Server will not be able to cache query plans for this kind of thing. As I said above - think about moving this kind of logic to application level.

Comment: ok it is working fine but i have a doubt. we don't know how many string will give the user how can i write procedure for that

Comment: in the above i give oscar,rahman,slumdog . if the user will give  any number of string at that time how can we write store procedure for that

Comment: You want to parse a comma separated string and search on that?